# How to add Jasmine settings to a "standalone" Jasmine setup (one using SpecRunner.html)

Tags: javascript, jasmine

There are lots of examples online on how to set up a standalone jasmine tests in a SpecRunner.html file, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <!-- include spec files here... -->
```

With this kind of setup, how would I configure Jasmine settings, like those found in the [node.js](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html#using-the-library) or [gulp](https://github.com/jasmine/gulp-jasmine-browser#options) setup? I'm talking about things like `random: false`, setting a random seed, and other settings that aren't runner-specific.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the settings are passed in through URL params, when requesting the page. I discovered some of these through the "options" box, which appears at the top right of the page:

[image: screenshot of options box on the default SpecRunnter.html page]

Here's a list of the params I was able to find (I'm not sure if this is all of them):

- `random=true`
- `throwFailures=true`
- `failFast=true`
- `seed=87816`

And here's an example request, with the above settings:

```
GET localhost:8080/SpecRunner.html?random=true&throwFailures=true&failFast=true&seed=87816
```